# How can I split a Grid into sub-Grids with different color maps?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colormap

Let assume that i have a grid given by

```
x = numpy.linspace(0, 10 , 1000)

y = numpy.linspace(1 , 5, 1000)

X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x,y)
```

Now, let us a define operations over X and Y.

For example,

```
G = X*X -Y

F = Y*Y*Y

Z = X/Y
```

The Function that i want to plot is let's say the sum of them,
`Q = G + F + Z`.

If a choose an arbitrary color map (for example "jet"), 
Python returns this function from the maximum value (red) to the minimum (blue). What i want to do is something a little bit more sofisticated: I want to plot Q but G in one color, F in another color and Z in another color.

Is this even possible?
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Do you want to plot all those functions on the same plot?  If not then of course you can just make separate plots each with its own colormap - are you wanting to join them side by side maybe?  In any case you can roll your own colormap, mapping a single-valued function to RGB values.

Comment: _"I want to plot Q but G in one color, F in another color and Z in another color."_ I'm not sure what you mean by this, since Q = G + F + Z. Do you mean something [like this (first example)](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-demo-py)? You can define your own colormaps, but I'm not sure if you're asking for help to plot each matrix together (so Q in one plot) or each separately (G, F, Z in separate plots each).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick answer.                                                               What I intend to do is plotting all functions (G,F,Z) on the same plot, each of one with its own color. However, i do not want its individual color as a "colormap" since it will be ranged from its maximum value to its minimum value by default. My aim is to distiguish G (for example in red) and F(for example in green) from Z(in black). Can be this done? Thank you very much :)

Comment: All three functions G, F, and Z are defined over the same domain. So, evaluating the function at a point, say, (1,1) will give you one value for each function, G(1,1), F(1,1) and Z(1,1). If you colorcode those values you will have 3 different colors, all to be shown at the same location (1,1). How do you imagine to discriminate between them, given that a pixel can either be red, or blue, or green, but not all at once?

Comment: Btw. you need to write @user if you want user to be notified of a response in comments. Else they won't read it.